# Adding Gson to netbeans java project

Tags: java, netbeans, gson, netbeans-8

I have downloaded gson.jar from its source.

Right-clicked at libraries folder -> add new -> add jar -> gson.jar

However when i try to  use

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

It complains that it cannot find symbol Gson.

What is the right way how to add gson to the project? I am not using maven

Thanks for help!

Comment: The answer posted user3238382 is correct or else you can use `ALT + ENTER` key to import Gson class.

Answer (score 15):

Go to [Download Gson](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.8.0%7C)

There, access last Gson version:

[image]

You will see sth like this:

[image]

In order to import  Gson using netbeans you will need to download 3 files from here:

- gson-2.8.0.jar   (classpath)
- gson-2.8.0-sources.jar   (sources)
- gson-2.8.0-javadoc.jar   (javadoc)

Then, you have to create a library on netbeans:

- Right click on Libraries (inside the project in which you want to add Gson)
- Properties
- In categories:  Libraries
- Add Library (write a name, e.g.: Gson)
- You have to import the right file in each of the tabs: classpath, sources, javadoc

[image]

It should work now!

Answer (score 2):

I am new to this. I used the same method of import that you used. It told me that it cannot find symbol Gson so I used CTRL+SHIFT+I to import correct library for gson and now everything is ok. You can also add this import statement   import com.google.gson.Gson; to the top of the page. I do apologize about the non-technical formatting of this paragraph.