# Gson Type class not found Error

Tags: java, netbeans, gson

I have netbeans and I added a Gson library with {"classpath" : gson-2.8.0.jar} and {"sources" : gson-2.8.0-sources.jar} and {"javadoc" : gson-2.8.0-javadoc.jar}, as suggested in this post:

[Adding Gson to netbeans java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332506/adding-gson-to-netbeans-java-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Now when I create java file below:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.*;
class test{
    Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>(){
        {
            put(1,new HashSet<Integer>(){{add(3); add(2);}};
        }
    };
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>>() { }.getType();
    String jsonMap = gson.toJson(map, Map.class);

}
```

I seem to have forgetten to include main method but you know what the code means. When I run this I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol symbol: class Type
```

According to the other post I shoudl have gotten everything I need from that download, but for some reason the Type class wasnt in the files. How do I fix this please I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add import statement

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
```

Its part of java language, not from external libraries.

Try to use automatic import shortcuts. For eclipse **(Ctrl + Shift + O)**. For netbeans I am not sure may be **(Ctrl + Shift + I)**

Comment: oh i see. I thought it would be included in gson. Also thanks for the neat trick, I appreciate your helpfulness.